# PyAPNS SSL3_WRITE_PENDING error

Tags: python, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm using PyAPNS module and Bottle framework in demo of my app to send push notifications to all registered devices.
At the beginning everything works fine, I've followed manual for PyAPNS. But after some time my service is running in the background on server, I start to recieve error:

SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1217: error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write retry

After restarting service everything works fine again. What should I do with that? Or how should I run such service in background? (for now I'm just running it in another screen)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue as you did when using this library (I'm assuming you are in fact using https://github.com/simonwhitaker/PyAPNs, which is what I'm using. There is at least one other lib out there with a similar name, but I don't think you'd be using that).

AFAIK when you're using the simple notification service the APNS server might hang up on you for reasons including: using an incorrect token, having a malformed request, etc. Or perhaps your connection might get broken if your network connection drops out or you. The PyAPNS code doesn't handle such a hangup very gracefully right now and it attempts to re-use the socket even after it has been closed. My experience with seeing the SSL3_WRITE_PENDING error was that I would always see an error such as "error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out" happen on the socket before I would then get SSL3_WRITE_PENDING error when PyAPNS tried to re-use the socket.

If you are seeing the server hangup on you and you want to know why it's doing that, it helps to use the enhanced version of APNS, so that the server will write back info about what you did wrong.

As it happens, there is currently a pull request (https://github.com/simonwhitaker/PyAPNs/pull/23/files) that both moves PyAPNS to use enhanced APNS AND handles disconnections more gracefully. You'll see I commented on that pull request and have created my own fork of PyAPNS that handles disconnections in the way that suited my use case the best.

So you can use the code from pull request to perhaps find out why the APNS server is hanging up on you. And / or you could use it to simplify your failure recovery so you just retry the send if an exception is thrown rather than have to re-create the APNS object.

Hopefully the pull request will be merged to master soon (possibly including my changes as well).